# PHP recursively removing folders

Tags: php, recursion, unlink, rmdir

Here is function that I'm using for recursively deleting folders and files

```
function rmdir_recursively($dir) {
    if (!is_dir($dir) || is_link($dir)) return unlink($dir); 
        foreach (scandir($dir) as $file) { 
            if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue; 
            if (!rmdir_recursively($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file)) { 
                chmod($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file, 0777); 
                if (!rmdir_recursively($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file)) return false; 
            }; 
        } 
        return rmdir($dir); 
}
```

The problem is, when I send some folder inside root, it deletes this folder. But when I send root folder itself like that

```
rmdir_recursively("./");
```

It returns bunch of errors like below

```
PHP Warning:  unlink(.//wp/wp-admin/network) [<a href='function.unlink'>function.unlink</a>]: No such file or directory in /home/vefa/public_html/deploy.php on line 52
[07-Oct-2012 02:16:09] PHP Warning:  unlink(.//wp/wp-admin/user) [<a href='function.unlink'>function.unlink</a>]: No such file or directory in /home/vefa/public_html/deploy.php on line 52
[07-Oct-2012 02:16:09] PHP Warning:  unlink(.//wp/wp-content) [<a href='function.unlink'>function.unlink</a>]: No such file or directory in /home/vefa/public_html/deploy.php on line 52
[07-Oct-2012 02:16:09] PHP Warning:  unlink(.//wp/wp-content/plugins) [<a href='function.unlink'>function.unlink</a>]: No such file or directory in /home/vefa/public_html/deploy.php on line 52
[07-Oct-2012 02:16:09] PHP Warning:  unlink(.//wp/wp-content/plugins/akismet) [<a href='function.unlink'>function.unlink</a>]: No such file or directory in /home/vefa/public_html/deploy.php on line 52
```

What am I missing?

Comment: why not do it in 1 line: `exec('rm -fr $path');`

Comment: @JvdBerg 2 questions: Will it work on shared server? And how to exclude script itself from deletion?

Comment: Most shared hosters allow you to do this.

Comment: @JvdBerg how to exclude script itself?

Comment: you could modify access rights, or use find with exec to delete and exclude the script. Or move the ecript away, delete and then move back. The os is made for file handling, php not. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @JvdBerg http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17593/room

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you're sending it `rmdir_recursively("./");`?

But look at the code, you are later calling `rmdir_recursively($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file)`.

This means that you'll be trying to eliminate files in ".//".

Which is why your error message contains `unlink(.//wp/wp-admin/user)`

Use `rmdir_recursively(".");` instead.